# Unix named pipe, multiple writers or multiple pipes

Tags: c, unix, pipe, named-pipes

I am currently measuring performance of named pipe to compare with another library.

I need to simulate a clients (n) / server (1) situation where server read messages and do a simple action for every written messages. So clients are writers.

My code now work, but if I add a 2nd writer, the reader (server) will never see the data and will not receive forever. The file is still filled with the non-read data at the end and read method will return 0.

Is it ok for a single named pipe to be written by multiple-process? Do I need to initialize it with a special flag for multiple-process?

I am not sure I can/should use multiple writers on a single pipe. But, I am not sure also it would be a good design to create 1 pipe for each clients.

Would it be a more standard design to use 1 named pipe per client connection?

I know about Unix Domain Name Socket and it will be use later. I need o make the named pipes work.

Comment: What is your actual question? You've described some code which doesn't work. But you don't seem to be asking about that code or why it isn't working. So please clarify what your question is.

Comment: I added clear questions

Comment: Show the code that doesn't work.